# Split number to range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have number, let's say 1000. Then I have range of values, it is changing according to calculation. I need to include 1000 to my calculation. So it should count amount of cells in Column B and split 1000 between cells in Column C.

I have tried following formula but it does not work correctly:

```
=IFERROR(CEILING($A$1/COUNT($B$4:$B$10);1);"")
```

Here is output:

[image]

Output should be:

[image]

If I will add value to Item 3, output should be:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use an IF:

```
=IF(B23<>"";CEILING($A$1/COUNT($B$23:$B$29);1);"")
```

then the sum:

```
=IF(C23<>"";SUM(B23:C23);"")
```

[image]